# stretching image in sdl2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Is stretching image in sdl2 makes the program slower?

For example if my map tile's native resolution is 32x32 and I stretch it in sdl to and make it 64x64, will it affect the program's speed?

Here's how I load my image:

```
SDL_Surface *surface = NULL;
SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;

surface = IMG_Load("sample.png");//this is the 32x32 image
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

SDL_Rect dstRect = {0, 0, 64, 64};//and I will use this rect for that sample.png in SDL_RenderCopy();
```

Comment: Rendering four times more pixels is slower. If the question is are you going to notice any slowdown - that one is impossible to answer without full knowledge of what you're doing. If you're rendering a billion of that tiles - well, maybe? If not - very unlikely.

Comment: Why not simply profile it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if will be resized each time when repainting. If you need to have resized tile, you should create cache with resized tiles (resize it on start, and use the cached tile on repaint). `SDL_BlitScaled` for surface, or `SDL_CreateTexture(surface, format, target, width, height)` for texture can be used to do it.